# Can a m3u8 file have no video?

Tags: ffmpeg, hls.js

We use m3u8 master files to bundle together video and several audios within, it's a musical app, so what really matters here are the audios, where we switch between instruments while playing the master file with `hls`.

I've been asked to check if an m3u8 can be played in HLS without containing video. Only containing several audios. Is this possible?

My backend team mate created one without it and it doesn't seem to work.

I tested it here[enter link description here](https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/?src=https%3A%2F%2Faltodevstorage.blob.core.windows.net%2Fplan%2F03062022110828master.m3u8&demoConfig=eyJlbmFibGVTdHJlYW1pbmciOnRydWUsImF1dG9SZWNvdmVyRXJyb3IiOnRydWUsInN0b3BPblN0YWxsIjpmYWxzZSwiZHVtcGZNUDQiOmZhbHNlLCJsZXZlbENhcHBpbmciOi0xLCJsaW1pdE1ldHJpY3MiOi0xfQ==) but it fails.